# Direct comparator in Java out of the box

Tags: java, collections, guava, comparator, comparable

I have a method which needs a `Comparator` for one of its parameters. I would like to pass a `Comparator` which does a *normal* comparison and a *reverse* comparator which does in reverse.

`java.util.Collections` provides a `reverseOrder()` this is good for the reverse comparison, but I could not find any normal `Comparator`.

The only solution what came into my mind is `Collections.reverseOrder(Collections.reverseOrder())`. but I don't like it because the double method calling inside.

Of course I could write a `NormalComparator` like this:

```
public class NormalComparator<T extends Comparable> implements Comparator<T> {
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

But I'm really surprised that Java doesn't have a solution for this out of the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most places where you can specify a `Comparator` also have a version without using a `Comparator` at all in which case it uses the natural order (i.e. it expects all objects to implement `Comparable` and uses `compareTo`).

So the usualy solution to this is to not specify a `Comparator` at all. Do you have a specific case where *only* the `Comparator` approach is supported?

If you absolutely need it, the [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) (as well as [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), which is a superset of the Google Collections) provides [`Ordering.natural()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#natural()) which returns [a `Ordering` object](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) that represent the natural order as defined by the `Comparable` interface. `Ordering` implements `Comparator`, so you can simply use that.

Comment: It's my method so it does not have a natural order. (actually it has, because I wrote it to work, but I didn't want to, I'm looking for a nicer solution)

Comment: And yes, I wrote it because I looked the source of `HashTree`.

Comment: @KARASZI: which `HashTree` are you talking about? There's no such class in Java SE. Did you mean `TreeMap`?

Comment: sorry, yes I meant `TreeMap`! :)

Comment: `Ordering.natural()` is actually a nice starting point when composing Comparators using `Functions` (`Ordering.onResultOf(..)`), because usually every comparision boiles down to comparing `Strings`, `Numbers`, ... which all implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm really surprised that Java doesn't have a solution for this out of the box.

I suppose it would be useful in a few cases ... like yours.  But in *most* use-cases an application would simply use the object's `compareTo` method directly.  Indirecting via an `Comparator` object would serve no purpose ... most of the time.

My guess is that the designers of those Java APIs did not consider your use-case important enough to support directly.  Besides, your implementation is only four lines of code.

The Java class libraries are not perfect.  Learn to live with it :-).

Comment: And they accepting a `null` in every method where a `Comparator` was needed (and they pasted the `compareTo` method instead of creating a new `NaturalComparator` instead), so not really a **DRY** solution. me thinks...

Answer (score 0):

For reverse ordering  use `Collections.reverseOrder()` ...

> Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse of the natural ordering on a
>   collection of objects that implement the Comparable interface.

Comment: you did not understand the question. I want a direct as well, not just the reverse. The double reverse could be the normal

Comment: @István: For natural ordering implement simple NaturalComparator for Comparable objects. I cannot find one in standard libraries.

Comment: it was in the OP, as you could see

Comment: @István: yes I know, unfortunately I'm afraid that there isn't better answer than that :-(

Answer (score 0):

There is *usually* no need for a natural order `Comparator<T>`, since *usually* there's an overload that takes a `Comparable<T>`. You can always follow the example set by `Collections.reverseOrder()` and write something like this:

```
private static final Comparator<?> NATURAL_ORDER =
   new Comparator<Comparable<Object>>() {
     @Override public int compare(Comparable<Object> o1, Comparable<Object> o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
     }
   };

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Comparator<T> naturalOrder() {
    return (Comparator<T>) NATURAL_ORDER;
}
```

You can then write something like:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Bob", "Alice", "Carol");
Collections.sort(names, naturalOrder());
System.out.println(names);
// prints "[Alice, Bob, Carol]"
```

Comment: as you could see in the OP, that's what I did!